# Material setting for J3D causes a non-textured object

Tags: java, java-3d

I am using the Java3D graphics engine(Don't ask) and while setting up some basic functions came across a strange bug/mistake in my code.

When creating a cube in J3D you need to specify the material and enable material showing - but when running the program all I ever get is 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37T6T.png)

Here is the problematic class:

```
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;
import javax.vecmath.*;

public class Main {

    SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
    BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
    public Main() {

        createCube(0.4f, -0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.2f, 0.2f, new Material(new Color3f( .5f, .5f, .5f),new Color3f( .5f, .5f, .5f),new Color3f( .5f, .5f, .5f),new Color3f( .5f, .5f, .5f),0.1f));

        createDirectionalLight(0.4f, 0.1f, 0.1f, new Color3f(1f, 1f, 1f), new Vector3f(4.0f, -7.0f, -12.0f), 1f);

        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);

    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        System.out.println("Hello System!");
        System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
        new Main();

    }
    private void createDirectionalLight(float x, float y, float z, Color3f color, Vector3f direction, float size) {

        TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        Transform3D transform3D = new Transform3D();
        Vector3f vector = new Vector3f(x, y, z);
        DirectionalLight light = new DirectionalLight(color, direction);
        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(x, y, z), size);

        light.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        transform3D.setTranslation(vector);
        transformGroup.setTransform(transform3D);
        transformGroup.addChild(light);
        group.addChild(transformGroup);

    }
    private void createCube(float x, float y, float z, float sizeX, float sizeY, float sizeZ, Material material) {

        Appearance appearance = new Appearance();
        appearance.setMaterial(material);
        TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        Transform3D transform3D = new Transform3D();
        Vector3f vector = new Vector3f(x, y, z);
        Box cube = new Box(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ, appearance);
        cube.setCapability(Box.ENABLE_APPEARANCE_MODIFY);
        transform3D.setTranslation(vector);
        transformGroup.setTransform(transform3D);
        transformGroup.addChild(cube);
        group.addChild(transformGroup);

    }

}
```

(To run the above code you need to import the jars from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-java-client-downloads.html#license-lightbox), unpackage the zip and import the jars found inside)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You use an obsolete version of Java3D, I remind you that Oracle stopped maintaining it more than 10 years ago. I advise you to use Java3D >= 1.6.

Comment: goessej as I mentioned I have my reason for using J3D - anyway I am using the latest version I can see on Oracle’s website

Comment: You misunderstood what I wrote. You're not using the latest version, you're using the latest version available on Oracle's website whereas Oracle stopped maintaining Java3D more than 10 years ago. The latest backward compatible version is Java3D 1.6, the latest version (not backward compatible) is Java3D 1.7. Those two versions have been maintained by the JogAmp community. You won't get any help if you stick with Java3D 1.5. You can find some information about the current state of Java3D in the official JogAmp wiki: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Java3D

Answer (score 0):

In the material class you are setting all the colors to

0.5f,0.5f,0.5f which is white "INCLUDING THE EMMISIVE COLOR" which overwrites all color from any light source and even vertex color

Set the 2nd component of your material to black color